# What is the appropriate machine learning algorithm for a restaurant's sales prediction?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to estimate the sales of a restaurant three days in advance, so that the staff can order fresh ingredients in time. I started off using linear regression, but noticed the following:
For the restaurant it is worse, if a customer won't get the food he ordered, compared to the case that food that is eventually thrown away. 
I figured I might just need a skewed cost function, but I am not sure. Maybe there is something already implemented.

Another question: Some days, there are some reservations (pre-orders) for the restaurant, so I know they will need at least a certain amount. How to include that?

Thank you!

Comment: please add some code and data at least - you are unlikely to get any responses without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: and your question might be more profitably addressed http://stats.stackexchange.com/ or http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was going to explain in detail how to do it at DS.SX but you deleted your question... The short answer is that you need to use an asymmetric loss function.

Comment: I just read that different weights for my data points might be the simplest solution and I thought I had it. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty general question, requiring more than a stack overflow response.  The first thing I'd consider is setting up a predictive algorithm like the linear regression you spoke of.  You can also add a constant to it, as in mx+b where the B is the known quantity of food for reservations.  So you would run linear regression, and then add a constant to the finalized prediction approximating the impact of reservations.  As you get more data, you could start to incorporate reservations as a variable to your model.  From there, you would want to build another model for estimating the amount to buy, because you are going to have a cost function that places more emphasis on having extra vs too little. You would have to know the cost vs. the profit to develop an algorithm for calculating the risk associated with too much food vs. too little, but it would not be difficult.  You might want to research profit curves: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profit_maximization

Hopefully that's enough to get you started!